# Im failing to authenticate Big query from my node.js firebase functions index.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am using the big query API in my firebase functions index.js file, but I keep getting an internal server error when initializing the Big query instance, my first attempt was to include my service account key file in the functions directory and my code is below

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

const app = express();
app.use(cors);
app.use(express.json());



exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);


app.post('/create_table', (req, res) => {

  'use strict';

  const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
  const options = {
    keyFilename: 'gamelot-c057c-837d4660ae39.json',
    projectId: 'gamelot-c057c',
  };
  const bigquery = new BigQuery(options);
```

this is the line causing the error

```
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
      const options = {
        keyFilename: 'gamelot-c057c-837d4660ae39.json',
        projectId: 'gamelot-c057c',
      };
      const bigquery = new BigQuery(options);
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cloud Functions for Firebase (i.e. Cloud Functions deployed via the Firebase CLI), you should not pass any options when creating the BigQuery client. Just do as follows:

```
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();
```

---

As a matter of fact, Cloud Functions for Firebase use the App Engine default service account, i.e. `{project-id}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`, which has an Editor [role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles), which, by default, contains permissions to interact with BigQuery.

You can check [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) if the Editor "basic" role has the desired permissions.

Comment: i change the role of  App Engine default service account to owner but Im still getting the error

Comment: You don't have to change the role of the service account. You should first check if the service account has the requested bigquery permissions, e.g. `bigquery.datasets.get`.